# Getting the maximum data an algorithm can process in a certain time span

Tags: algorithm, measurement

Well meanwhile it's the second time I got an exercise where I have to determine (in this case it's about sorting algorithms) how many numbers I can sort with a certain algorithm (on my own computer) so that the algorithm would run exactly one minute.

This is a practical exercise, means I must generate enough numbers so it would run that long. Now I ask myself, since I haven't had this problem in all ten years of programming: How can I possibly do this? My first attempt was a bit brute-forcy which resulted in an instant StackOverflow.

I could make an array (or multiple) and fill them up with random numbers, but to determine how many would end up in one minute runtime would be a terrible long task since you would always need to wait.

What can I do to efficiently find out about this? Measuring the difference between let's say 10 and 20 numbers and calculate how much it would take to fill a minute? Sounds easy, but algorithms (especially sorting algorithms) are rarely linear.

Comment: A simple way would be to double the size until you get a run time of over one minute and then do a binary search on the final interval. The doubling and halving of the binary search step could be adapted if you know the time complexity of the measured algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You know time complexity for each algorithm in question. For example, bubble sort takes O(n*n) time. Make relatively small sample run - D=1000 records, measure the time it takes (T milliseconds). For example, it takes 15 seconds = 15000 milliseconds.

Now with more or less accuracy you can expect that D*2 records will be processed 4 times slower. And vice versa - you need about D* *sqrt(60000/T)* records to process them in 1 minute. For example, you need D* sqrt(60000/15000)=D* sqrt(4)=D*2=2000 records.

This method is not accurate enough to get exact number, and in most cases exact number of records is not set, it fluctuates from run to run. Also for many algorithms time it takes depends on values in your record set. For example, worst case for quicksort is O(n*n), while normal case is O(n*log(n))

Comment: Well, I guess that method should do the trick. I guess it's okay to use the normal case complexity. I mean how else am I supposed to do this? This would require a very thorough test environment if I wanted to really find out. I guess I'll calculate that and run a test run - then I'll see how close I am to the real value.

Comment: Ok, I'm close. But the delta is quite big. I'd like to narrow it down a bit using multiple passes. Can I reuse this equation to calculate how many less/more I can process to get close to the minute (using the delta time `oneMinute - actualTime`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
long startTime = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
int times = 0;
boolean done = false;
while(!done){
//run algorithm
times++;
if(System.getCurrentTimeMillis()-startTime >= 60000)
    done = true;
}
```

Or if you don't want to wait that long you can can replace the 60000 by 1000 and then multiply the times by 60, it won't be very accurate though.

It would be time consuming to generate a new number every time, so you can use an array that you populate beforehand and then access with the times variable, or you can always use the same variable, which you know would be most time consuming to process so that you get the minimum amount of times that it would run in a minute.

Comment: The main problem is that the algorithm is usually not linear. I.e. running it `k` times with `n` items does not require the same time as running it once with `n * k` items. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: Moreover it's what I meant with brute-forcey approach. You end up testing it several times and you might get close to the correct value, but you only know after a minute or less or more. So you end up trying ages to find it out. There must be a way that takes less time.